# Create rewrite rule on IIS to redirect to subdirectory on same server

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

I have a website structure like this:

```
https://example.org/
                    october-2018/
                                 index.html
                                 css/...
                                 js/...
                    november-2019/
                                 index.html
                                 css/...
                                 js/...
                    march-2020/
                                 index.html
                                 css/...
                                 js/...
                    ...
```

I would like to create a IIS Rewrite rule that will rewrite a request for just the bare domain URL (https://example.org/) to serve the contents of, say, the `november-2019/` directory. I cannot find any examples and I'm not IIS-savvy enough to get my head around this (much easier for me if it were Apache or nginx ...).

In case it matters: As I'm in a corporate environment, I don't think the Application Request Routing (ARR) extension is available on the platform I have to use.

Comment: is your issue resolved?

Comment: Yes, thanks for reminding. I will add my own answer as yours wasn't clear to me; and I didn't have time to ask for clarifications. Thanks for your input though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, after a lot of trial and error, I was able to create the following rule:

```
<rule name="Redirect to specific local subdirectory" enabled="true" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="^$" />
   <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
   <action type="Rewrite" url="november-2019/" />
</rule>
```

This works for the parent directory in the same way as for the child directory. However, all assets (fonts, images, css, etc.) need to use the absolute URL to the `november-2019/` directory.

Unfortunately, I couldn't use @Jalpha's rules as I wasn't sure how to use them. I appreciate the effort though.

Answer (score 0):

You could use below url rewrite rule:

```
    <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule5" stopProcessing="true">
           <match url="^$" />
           <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
           <action type="Rewrite" url="http://www.sample1.com/november-2019/" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
     </rule>

   <outboundRules>
    <rule name="rule5" preCondition="ResponseIsHtml1" stopProcessing="true">
            <match filterByTags="Link, Script" pattern="(.*)" />
            <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="on" />
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="www.sample1.com" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" value="/november-2019{R:1}" />
            </rule>
   <preConditions>
          <preCondition name="ResponseIsHtml1" logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
           <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="text/html" />
           </preCondition>

    </outboundRules>
```